# Judgecode -- Sort with swap (2)

Tags: algorithm, jobs

The problem I've seen is as bellow, anyone has some idea on it?
http://judgecode.com/problems/1011

Given a permutation of integers from 0 to n - 1, sorting them is easy. But what if you can only swap a pair of integers every time?

Please calculate the minimal number of swaps

Answer (score 1):

One classic algorithm seems to be permutation cycles (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_notation#Cycle_notation). The number of swaps needed equals the total number of elements subtracted by the number of cycles.

For example:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 5 4 3 1

Start with 1 and follow the cycle:
1 down to 2, 2 down to 5, 5 down to 1.

1 -> 2 -> 5 -> 1
3 -> 4 -> 3
```

We would need to swap index 1 with 5, then index 5 with 2; as well as index 3 with index 4. Altogether 3 swaps or `n - 2`. We subtract `n` by the number of cycles since cycle elements together total `n` and each cycle represents a swap less than the number of elements in it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple implementation in `C` for the above problem. The algorithm is similar to User **גלעד ברקן**:

- Store the position of every element of `a[]` in `b[]`. So, `b[a[i]] = i`
- Iterate over the initial array `a[]` from left to right.
- At position `i`, check if `a[i]` is equal to `i`. If `yes`, then keep iterating.
- If `no`, then it's time to swap. Look at the logic in the code minutely to see how the swapping takes place. **This is the most important step as both array `a[]` and `b[]` needs to be modified.** Increase the `count` of swaps.

Here is the implementation:

```
long long sortWithSwap(int n, int *a) {
  int *b = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);  //create a temporary array keeping track of the position of every element
  int i,tmp,t,valai,posi;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    b[a[i]] = i;
  }
  long long ans = 0;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(a[i]!=i){
      valai = a[i];
      posi = b[i];
      a[b[i]] = a[i];
      a[i] = i;
      b[i] = i;
      b[valai] = posi;
      ans++;
    }
  }
  return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The essence of solving this problem lies in the following observation
1. The elements in the array do not repeat 
2. The range of elements is from 0 to n-1, where n is the size of the array.

The way to approach
After you have understood the way to approach the problem ou can solve it in linear time.

Imagine How would the array look like after sorting all the entries ? 
It will look like arr[i] == i, for all entries . Is that convincing ?

First create a bool array named FIX, where FIX[i] == true if ith location is fixed, initialize this array with false initially

Start checking the original array for the match arr[i] == i, till the time this condition holds true, eveything is okay. While going ahead with traversal of array also update the FIX[i] = true.
 The moment you find that arr[i] != i
 you need to do something, arr[i] must have some value x such that x > i, how do we guarantee that ?  The guarantee comes from the fact that  the elements in the array do not repeat, therefore if the array is sorted till index i then it means that the element at position i in the array cannot come from left but from right. 
Now the value x is essentially saying about some index , why so because the array only has elements till n-1 starting from 0, and in the sorted arry every element i of the array must be at location i.
what does arr[i] == x means is that , not only element i is not at it's correct position but also the element x is missing from it's place.
Now to fix ith location you need to look at xth location, because maybe xth location holds i and then you will swap the elements at indices i and x, and get the job done.
 But wait, it's not necessary that the index x will hold i (and you finish fixing these locations in just 1 swap). Rather it may be possible that index x holds value y, which again will be greater than i, because array is only sorted till location i.
Now before you can fix position i , you need to fix x, why ? we will see later.
 So now again you try to fix position x, and then similarly you will try fixing till the time you don't see element i at some location in the fashion told .
The fashion is to follow the link from arr[i], untill you hit element i at some index. 
It is guaranteed that you will definitely hit i at some location while following in this way . Why ?  try proving it, make some examples, and you will feel it
Now you will start fixing all the index you saw in the path following from index i till this index (say it j). Now what you see is that the path which you have followed is a circular one and for every index i, the arr[i] is tored at it's previous index (index from where you reached here), and Once you see that you can fix the indices, and mark all of them in FIX array to be true. Now go ahead with next index of array and do the same thing untill whole array is fixed.. 
This was the complete idea, but to only conunt no. of swaps, you se that once you have found a cycle of n elements you need n swaps, and after doing that you fix the array , and again continue. So that's how you will count the no. of swaps.
Please let me know if you have some doubts in the approach .
You may also ask for C/C++ code help. 
 Happy to help  :-)